# str replace and regex matching in dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, str-replace, gsub

i have messy data file names and want to clean them systematically. 37 unique file names all with 4 pieces of information, age, genotype, mice, and section. I bolded the info in a few examples.

I can do something manual like

```
year_sub<- str_replace_all(year_sub$year_sub, "mdx 1yr #1 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Res", "mdx 1yr #1 1")
year_sub <- as.data.frame(year_sub)
```

but this only works for 1 type of data. I've looked into using gsub and str_replace_all but having lots of trouble. Any advice?

```
[1] "1month/1month/x25/**1month** **mdx** **#3** 25x_**1**/Results/Results.txt"                 
 [2] "1month/1month/x25/**1month** **mdx** **#3** 25x_**2**/Results/Results.txt"                 
 [3] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"                 
 [4] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"                 
 [5] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"                 
 [6] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"                 
 [7] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_1/Results/Results.txt"             
 [8] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_2/Results/Results.txt"             
 [9] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_3/Results/Results.txt"             
[10] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_1/Results/Results.txt"             
[11] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_2/Results/Results.txt"             
[12] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_3/Results/Results.txt"             
[13] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"             
[14] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"             
[15] "1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"             
[16] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/**mdx** **1yr** **#1** Pax7 Laminin 10x_**1**/Results/Results.txt"    
[17] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #2 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"    
[18] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #3 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"    
[19] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #4 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"    
[20] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #1 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"
[21] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #2 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"
[22] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #3 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"
[23] "1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #4 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt"
[24] "4month/x25/4month mdx  #1 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"                       
[25] "4month/x25/4month mdx  #1 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"                       
[26] "4month/x25/4month mdx  #2 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"                       
[27] "4month/x25/4month mdx  #2 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"                       
[28] "4month/x25/4month mdx  #2 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"                       
[29] "4month/x25/4month mdx  #2R 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"                      
[30] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"                    
[31] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"                    
[32] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"                    
[33] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_1/Results/Results.txt"                    
[34] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"                    
[35] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"                    
[36] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #3 25x_2/Results/Results.txt"                    
[37] "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #3 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"
```

Comment: Would these also be file paths on a windows system?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(age     = str_extract(year_sub, "\\d+(yr|month)"),  
         genotyp = str_extract(year_sub, "\\bmdx\\w*"),
         mice    = str_extract(year_sub, "#\\d+"),
         section = str_extract(year_sub, "(?<=\\d(x|X)_)\\d+"))
```

To extract the age, we look for numbers (at least one) `\\d+` follows by `yr` or `month`. The genotyp is a word starting with `mdx` and everything that looks like a word (`\\w` means everything like letters and numbers and "_"). Mice is a number preceded by a "#" and finally the section is the number preceded by at least a number, an "x" or "X" and an "_".

This returns

```r
                                                                     year_sub    age genotyp mice section
1                   1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 1month     mdx   #3       1
2                   1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 1month     mdx   #3       2
3                   1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 1month     mdx   #3       3
4                   1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 1month     mdx   #4       1
5                   1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 1month     mdx   #4       2
6                   1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 1month     mdx   #4       3
7               1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_1/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #1       1
8               1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_2/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #1       2
9               1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_3/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #1       3
10              1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_1/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #2       1
11              1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_2/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #2       2
12              1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_3/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #2       3
13              1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #4       1
14              1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #4       2
15              1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 1month mdxJAG1   #4       3
16     1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #1 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr     mdx   #1       1
17     1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #2 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr     mdx   #2       1
18     1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #3 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr     mdx   #3       1
19     1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #4 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr     mdx   #4       1
20 1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #1 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr mdxJAG1   #1       1
21 1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #2 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr mdxJAG1   #2       1
22 1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #3 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr mdxJAG1   #3       1
23 1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #4 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt    1yr mdxJAG1   #4       1
24                         4month/x25/4month mdx #1 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 4month     mdx   #1       1
25                         4month/x25/4month mdx #1 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 4month     mdx   #1       2
26                         4month/x25/4month mdx #2 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 4month     mdx   #2       1
27                         4month/x25/4month mdx #2 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 4month     mdx   #2       2
28                         4month/x25/4month mdx #2 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 4month     mdx   #2       3
29                        4month/x25/4month mdx #2R 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 4month     mdx   #2       1
30                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #1       1
31                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #1       2
32                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #1       3
33                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_1/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #2       1
34                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #2       2
35                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #2       3
36                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #3 25x_2/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #3       2
37                     4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #3 25x_3/Results/Results.txt 4month mdxJAG1   #3       3
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(year_sub = c("1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #3 25x_3/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdx #4 25x_3/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #1 25X_3/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #2 25X_3/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"1month/1month/x25/1month mdxJAG1 #4 25x_3/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #1 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #2 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #3 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdx 1yr #4 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #1 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #2 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #3 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"1yr Pax7 Laminin/10x/mdxJAG1 1yr #4 Pax7 Laminin 10x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdx #1 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdx #1 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdx #2 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdx #2 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdx #2 25x_3/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdx #2R 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #1 25x_3/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_1/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #2 25x_3/Results/Results.txt", 
"4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #3 25x_2/Results/Results.txt", "4month/x25/4month mdxJAG1 #3 25x_3/Results/Results.txt"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```

Comment: Excellent! Nice job

Comment: This worked well. The pattern matching isn't that hard after you explained, thank you for spelling it out- still learning.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, if it helped you solving your problem. :-)